# BLE - SWIFT App doesn't display pairing request for writing into authentication characteristic

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an app to connect to a peripheral device that has one of the authentication characteristic that can be written to. The pass-code to connect to the characteristic is 123456. I use LightBlue Explorer to test and it successfully prompt the alert to input the pass code

### [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx68h.jpg)

However, when I try to pass a value with my app, it doesn't popup and I don't see any error pop up. Can you guys please advice me which method should I use to achieve such thing.

Here is my code

```

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class MainViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

let xxxxxxx_SERVICE = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
let TX_CHARACTERISTIC = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

var manager : CBCentralManager? = nil
var mainPeripheral : CBPeripheral? = nil
var writeCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic? = nil


@IBOutlet weak var upButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var downButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //addNavBarImage()

    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    customiseNavigationBar()

    // Continuous Hold UP Button
    let upButtonlongGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainViewController.upButtonlongTap))
    upButtonlongGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
    upButton.addGestureRecognizer(upButtonlongGesture)

    // Continuous Hold DOWN Button
    let downButtonlongGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainViewController.downButtonlongTap))
    downButtonlongGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
    downButton.addGestureRecognizer(downButtonlongGesture)
}

// MARK: - Update Navigation Bar Button

func addNavBarImage() {

    let navController = navigationController!
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "xxxxxxx_logo")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height



    let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - image.size.width / 2
    let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - image.size.height / 2
    print(bannerX)
    print(bannerY)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}

func customiseNavigationBar() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

    let rightButton = UIButton()

    if (mainPeripheral == nil) {
        rightButton.setTitle("Scan", for: [])
        rightButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: [])
        rightButton.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor.black, for: [])
        rightButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x : 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width : 60, height: 30))
        rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.scanButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    } else {
        rightButton.setTitle("Disconnect", for: [])
        rightButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: [])
        rightButton.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor.black, for: [])
        rightButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x : 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width : 100, height: 30))
        rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.disconnectButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    rightBarButton.customView = rightButton
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton

}

@objc func scanButtonPressed() {
    print("Scan Button Pressed")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "scan-segue", sender: nil)
}

@objc func disconnectButtonPressed() {
    print("Disconnect Button Pressed")
    manager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(mainPeripheral!)
    //uncomment after implemented ScanTableViewController
    //manager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(mainPeripheral)
}


// MARK: - Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "scan-segue" {
        let scanController : ScanTableViewController = segue.destination as! ScanTableViewController
        manager?.delegate = scanController
        scanController.manager = manager
        scanController.parentView = self

    }
}

// MARK - CBCentralManagerDelegate Methods

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    print("BLE Stack Started")

    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOff:
        print("Power is OFF")
        break

    case .resetting:
        print("Resetting")
        break

    case .poweredOn:
        print("Power is ON")
        break

    case .unauthorized:
        print("Unauthorized")
        break

    case .unsupported:
        print("Unsupported")
        break

    default:
        print("Unknown")
        break
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    mainPeripheral = nil
    customiseNavigationBar()

    // Show Pop Up Alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: "Disconnected \(peripheral.name ?? "") Successfully!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("Disconnected " + peripheral.name!)
}

// MARK - CBPeripheralDelegate Methods

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        print("Services found with UUID: " + service.uuid.uuidString)

        if (service.uuid.uuidString == "180A") {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }

        if (service.uuid.uuidString == "1800") {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }

        if ((service.uuid.uuidString == xxxxxx_SERVICE)) {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        let aCharacteristic = characteristic as CBCharacteristic
        print(aCharacteristic)
        if (aCharacteristic.uuid.uuidString == TX_CHARACTERISTIC) {
            writeCharacteristic = aCharacteristic
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - Button Pressed Characteristic

// Write Data
func writeBLEData(byte: [UInt8]) {
    let writeData = Data(bytes: byte)

    if mainPeripheral != nil {
        mainPeripheral?.writeValue(writeData, for: writeCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
    } else {
        print("Haven't discovered any device yet")
    }
}

// Write Value to Controller
@objc func upButtonlongTap(sender : UIGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.state == .ended {
        //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
        writeBLEData(byte: [0x00])
    }
    else if sender.state == .began {
        //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
        writeBLEData(byte: [0x01])
    }
}

@objc func downButtonlongTap(sender : UIGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.state == .ended {
        //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
        writeBLEData(byte: [0x00])
    }
    else if sender.state == .began {
        //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
        writeBLEData(byte: [0x02])
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Have you cleared the pairing you established with LightBlue before running your app?  What output do you get from your app?  Is it discovering/connecting/writing the data?  You should implement the `didWriteValueFor` peripheral delegate method so that you can check for write errors.

Comment: @Paulw11 I did clear the pairing, however nothing happened. The device was connected and didn't show any error when I try to write. I will try to implement the ```didWriteValuefor``` and let you know the result. However, should it be a function we have to write in our app to make the popup alert, or it is embedded into CoreBlueTooth?

Comment: As soon as you read or write to a characteristic that requires encryption, iOS will initiate pairing. You don’t need to write anything specific in your code.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you. How do I vote for correct answer?

Comment: I haven't provided an answer, just comments. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @Paulw11What is the best way to implemented ```didWriteValueFor``` ?.  I tried ``` if error != nil { print(error) } else { print("write successfully") } ``` but there is no log show up.

Comment: @Paulw11I fixed the problem. I have to changed the ```CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse``` to ```withResponse```

Comment: @Paulw11, i am working with Polar iOS SDK to connect BLE Heart Rate sensor. I discover with my own central object and send the peripheral to Polar SDK to connect sensor. Programmatically it connects well , giving data properly but each time i am getting an annoying "Paring request" alert.  i want to avoid/hide this alert paring alert. Someone says, it's from Polar Sensor encryption issue, others says it's from OS level. Can i ignore this Alert anyhow ? any idea  ?

Comment: If a peripheral specifies that encryption is required then a pairing dialog is shown.  Normally once you have paired a peripheral the dialog won't be shown unless you go to settings and "forget" it.

Comment: @AlexT: have u achieved this feature?

Comment: @Ben yes I did. Do you have a control of your BLE hardware code?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, I just want to know....In iOS is it possible to contorl the bonding? before bonding I need to ask the BLE PIN passkey to user and whatever thier entering that I need to get control. Hope u have achived same thing?

Comment: @Ben you will need to perform either read or write operation with the response as required parameter to start the ponding process. You cannot access the pincode or passcode as far as I know. Those information is handled by the BLE stack